# How to think about a vector space defined by continuous real valued functions on [a, b]?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Imagining a Euclidean space is natural even in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I am not sure how I am supposed to picture the "axes on the grid" of the set of continuous real valued functions over some interval.

Comment: In contrast to the post above, since (most) spaces have a basis (C[a,b]] has one, so called Schauder basis) there is a sequence say $f_n$ so that any continuous $f$ can be written in unique way as  $f = \sum a_kf_k$. So, one can think about $f_k$ as "axis" of $C[a,b]$..This concept is more obvious in "sequential" spaces, i.e. you should probably start with $l_2$ space as a natural extension of finite dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Comment: If you really can imagine $\mathbb{R}^n$ (wow!!!), $C([0,1])$ shouldn't be much of a challenge. Just keep trying!

Comment: @Salcio Thank you that helps!